# $ 0 = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow o^+} \int_{\Omega} \frac{ \chi( u + \varepsilon \xi > 0 ) - \chi(\{ u>0 \} ) }{\varepsilon}? $

Tags: analysis

Let $\Omega $ be a domain, $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ and $\xi \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\{u > 0\})$ you can assume that $\{u > 0\}$ is an open set. I'd like to know if in this situation we can conclude that
$$
0 = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow o^+} \int_{\Omega} \dfrac{ \chi( u + \varepsilon \xi >0 )  - \chi(\{ u>0 \} ) }{\varepsilon}?
$$
Where $\chi(A) $ is the characteristc function of a set $A$.
Or if can I  assume another similar condition for that the limit above be true.
This ask is motivated for instance by the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184069/a-type-of-local-minimum-2). I've also read other things that motivate this suspicion.

Comment: user: There is no need to make your title larger than other titles to questions. It is perfectly legible as is.